# function for solving equation R

Tags: r

I'm trying to solve

```
 $\sum_{j=1}^{180} x^{a_j} = 1$
```

[image]

I created two functions :

```
f1 <- function(x){c(rep(x,180))}
f2 <- function(x){sum(f1(x)^vec) - 1}
```

where `vec` is  my  `a_j` vector.

`uniroot` doesn't work. Which function should I use ?

Is there a better syntax ?

Comment: please edit your question to keep coherence with the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why doesn't `uniroot` work, actually? As long as you define correctly your function and the interval to look for it should work:

```
aj <- c(-4,-5,-3,-4,-2,-3,-1,-2,-7,-6,-5,-8,-7,-6,-6,-7,-5,-6,
        -4,-5,-3,-4,-9,-8,-7,-10,-9,-8,-1,-2,rep(-1,150))
f <- function(x,vec){sum(x^vec)-1}
uniroot(f, interval=c(-100,100), vec=aj)
$root
[1] -0.518658

$f.root
[1] -0.009276057

$iter
[1] 21

$estim.prec
[1] 6.103516e-05
```

Comment: Well that's simpler. Thank you.

Comment: I have just realized that there is a solution outside of the interval c(-100,100) but I can't seem to get it with uniroot because "f() values at end points not of opposite sign"

Comment: That's what I meant by "As long as you define correctly the interval to look for". I just used c(-100,100) as an example. If there are several solutions, nothing prevents you from running the function several times with different intervals.

Comment: Yes but the problem is I can't get the solution (152.0198652) with an interval that allows for this solution.

Comment: Of course you can: `uniroot(f, interval=c(100,200), vec=aj)` or even `uniroot(f, interval=c(0,200), vec=aj)` (i.e. anything that doesn't contain the other solution) gives 152.0199

Answer (score 2):

You can use `polyroot`, For example

```
 polyroot(c(-1,rep(1,180)))
```

here

```
 p(x) = -1 + 1 * x + … + 1 * x^180
```

**EDIT** To use your vector *aj*

It is not clear what is your vector `vec` , I guess you want something like this :

```
 polyroot(c(-1,vec))
```

Where vec

```
 vec = (a1,a2,..............,a180)
```

**EDIT** after OP clarification:

The OP wants to find the roots of polynome with negative exponents. The solution is to factorize by the max of the exponents to can apply `polyroot`.

```
vec <- c(-4,-5,-3,-4,-2,-3,-1,-2,-7,-6,-5,-8,-7,-6,-6,-7,-5,-6,
         -4,-5,-3,-4,-9,-8,-7,-10,-9,-8,-1,-2,rep(-1,150))
ma <- max(abs(vec))
vec <- sort(ma+vec)
polyroot(as.data.frame(table(vec))$Freq)
```

Comment: But if he actually has a pile of `a_j` exponents he'll have to list them.  His `f1` function is inconsistent with the image he posted.

Comment: polyroot(c(-1,vec)) doesn't solve my problem. I have tried it with vec = 2 and I get 0.5 instead of 1.
vec is a list of non ordered exponents

Comment: That's simply not what I want. In this example I'd like to solve -1 + x^2 = 0

Comment: The vec vector in your answer was spot on, it's just that I am trying to input them as exponents and not coefficients.